# How to perform PHP+Linux with VSTS 2008?

Tags: php, visual-studio, performance-testing

I have a site using PHP+Linux. I just want to use VSTS 2008 to do performance testing under it. As I used it on Microsoft technology: ASP.net, Windwos Server and so on, I don't make sure how to do this efficient testing like getting the counters under Linux. Thanks for the replay.

Comment: Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance.